# Form Closing event on gtk#

Tags: events, mono, gtk, monodevelop

In System.Windows.Forms, using C#, to access the form's closing event is FormClosed (if I am correct). I just want to know what is the equivalent of the FormClosed event in GTK# (I am using monodevelop's stetic designer).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the OnDeleteEvent:

```
protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BOOM");
    Application.Quit();
    a.RetVal = true;
}
```

`RetVal` says whether the event should bubble or not.